# Testing Sidekiq's retry queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, sidekiq, minitest

We have a fairly mission-critical component that clears out the Sidekiq retry queue for a certain item if certain criteria are met.  Sidekiq's testing API provided no way to add to the retry queue, so I we had to come up with something custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the retry queue:

```
  def add_retry(object: @object, klass: 'HardWorker', at: Time.now.to_f)
    payload = Sidekiq.dump_json(
      class: klass,
      args: [object.id, object.class, 'sidekiq_retry_test'],
      queue: 'user_integration',
      jid: rand(1..10000),
      retry_count: 20,
      failed_at: Time.now.to_f
    )

    Sidekiq.redis do |conn|
      conn.zadd('retry', at.to_s, payload)
    end
  end
```

You can change anything inside the payload hash.  You might want to specify the queue, or add a more robust solution to pick a job id.  This is just what worked for us.

You will need to clean up the retry queue after the fact. You should do this within a `teardown` or `after(:all)` block.

```
  def cleanup_retry_queue
    Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.each do |job|
      job.delete if job.args[2] == 'sidekiq_retry_test'
    end
  end
```

Remember, this will actually add to the queue, so be careful.  Only use this if you have a testable component that relies on retry queues.  Don't use this to test Sidekiq's queuing functionality itself.